# How to install CentOS 5 or Redhat 5 on USB Key or external HD

Tags: usb, centos, rhel-5

How to install CentOS 5 or Redhat 5 on USB key/HD external? I don't want to create multi-boot (with Windows 7)which mean just when I need a Linux machine by connecting usb I have downloaded LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8.5 but just for Centos 6 and redhat 6.1 so doesn't work with me because not version 5.
Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Any particular reason for not using the latest version of the distro?

You can try [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) which lists CentOS with no version number so may well work with 5.

Answer (score 1):

Does it not "just work"? I installed Ubuntu (first 9.04 and then 9.10) on a USB drive just from the normal install media back when my netbook's internal SSD decided not to play ball.