# Linux expert command - where should I enter?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I need to enter "Linux expert" at the boot prompt. I've centOS6.2 DVD but I'm not sure where exactly should I enter this & when will I get the boot prompt?

I put the DVD & rebooted & it gave me menu where it says "Install from DVD", etc.

Now, where can I enter "Linux expert" command?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It sounds like a prank I would pull on ppl. . .

Comment: I need to install centos on usb & hence the first step is to type linux expert on boot prompt..Howd do I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "Expert Mode"?  Can you provide a link to the "steps" you are looking at?

Comment: Perhaps see: [How to install CentOS 5 or Redhat 5 on USB Key or external HD](http://superuser.com/questions/360206/how-to-install-centos-5-or-redhat-5-on-usb-key-or-external-hd)

Comment: I read it from http://www.brool.com/index.php/installing-centos-on-an-external-usb-drive

Comment: techie007, that installation won't help me as the persistency setting cannot be set for more than 4 GB...I want to use all 80GB of my USB drive for centOS

Comment: The problem you are running into is that the instructions you are following are for v4.x (c. 2007) up to v5.5.  6.x has a new install system.  Try "Rescue installed system" if offered by the v6.x DVD, and that should get you a prompt you may be able to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link you posted to: [brool.com/index.php/installing-centos-on-an-external-usb-drive](http://www.brool.com/index.php/installing-centos-on-an-external-usb-drive)

"2. When you reboot, reboot to the CentOS CD AGAIN and type “linux rescue”."

When you boot your computer to an install/Live CD of some Linux flavors (Ubuntu is like this) you are presented with a menu that asks you what you want to do (install for different locales, test memory, edit boot options, etc...).  This sounds like the place where you need to be.

So I'm thinking that you need to boot into your CentOS install disc.  From there, you should be able to enter your "linux expert" command at the installation boot prompt.

I found a screenshot for CentOS5...not sure what it looks like for 6.
[image: CentOS 5 Installation Boot Prompt]